# How to expand and center contents of PDF file

Tags: pdf

This is an excerpt from a PDF document. It can be seen that there is a lot of space on the right and top of the page. This happens on each page. Some documents are even worse where the contents of each page are even smaller and leave event bigger part of the page completely blank.

How can this be fixed? I want to modify this PDF or create one from this, where the contents are in the center of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Is this a scan? From where this PDF is originated?

Comment: It appears to be scan of an ebook. I cannot trace the source I am afraid.

Comment: At least, all pages have same borders, i.e. a single profile of cropping filter could suffice, or it has to be adjusted for each page?

Answer (score 0):

If the whitespace is more or less the same on all pages, open the document in Acrobat (or another capable PDF viewer), and crop the page, then apply to the rest of the document.